# GWT compilation problem The constructor StackTraceElement(String, String, String, int) is undefined

Tags: gwt, compilation

I am compiling my GWT module in Eclipse that inherits my other module (that compiles without problems) and I get this output:

```
Compiling module mymodule.GWT_TESTS
   Validating newly compiled units
      [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/C:/apath/gwt-2.0.4/gwt-user.jar!/com/google/gwt/core/client/impl/StackTraceCreator.java'
         [ERROR] Line 70: The constructor StackTraceElement(String, String, String, int) is undefined
         [ERROR] Line 80: The constructor StackTraceElement(String, String, String, int) is undefined
         [ERROR] Line 158: The constructor StackTraceElement(String, String, String, int) is undefined
      [ERROR] Errors in 'file:/C:/apath/workspace/GWT_TESTS/src/mymodule/client/GWT_TESTS.java'
         [ERROR] Line 7: The import mymodule.shared.FieldVerifier cannot be resolved
         [ERROR] Line 122: FieldVerifier cannot be resolved
      [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/C:/apath/gwt-2.0.4/gwt-user.jar!/com/google/gwt/user/client/rpc/RpcRequestBuilder.java'
         [ERROR] Line 167: The method getPermutationStrongName() is undefined for the type GWT
      [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/C:/apath/gwt-2.0.4/gwt-user.jar!/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/TabLayoutPanel.java'
         [ERROR] Line 21: The import com.google.gwt.dom.client.Style.Display cannot be resolved
         [ERROR] Line 22: The import com.google.gwt.dom.client.Style.Unit cannot be resolved
         [ERROR] Line 118: Style.Float cannot be resolved
         [ERROR] Line 143: Unit cannot be resolved to a type
         [ERROR] Line 153: Unit cannot be resolved to a type
         [ERROR] Line 155: Unit cannot be resolved to a type
         [ERROR] Line 161: Unit cannot be resolved
         [ERROR] Line 161: Unit cannot be resolved
         [ERROR] Line 162: Unit cannot be resolved
         [ERROR] Line 167: Unit cannot be resolved
         [ERROR] Line 390: Display cannot be resolved
         [ERROR] Line 397: The method clearDisplay() is undefined for the type Style
         [ERROR] Line 481: Unit cannot be resolved
         [ERROR] Line 481: Unit cannot be resolved
         [ERROR] Line 482: Unit cannot be resolved to a type
         [ERROR] Line 482: Unit cannot be resolved
         [ERROR] Line 484: Display cannot be resolved
      [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/C:/apath/gwt-2.0.4/gwt-user.jar!/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/SubmitButton.java'
         [ERROR] Line 49: The method getButtonElement() from the type Button is not visible
         [ERROR] Line 62: The method createSubmitButtonElement() is undefined for the type Document
[ERROR] Unexpected
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompiledClass.<init>(CompiledClass.java:81)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.JdtCompiler$FindTypesInCud.visit(JdtCompiler.java:204)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration.traverse(TypeDeclaration.java:1198)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.CompilationUnitDeclaration.traverse(CompilationUnitDeclaration.java:687)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.JdtCompiler$CompilerImpl.process(JdtCompiler.java:158)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:444)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.JdtCompiler.doCompile(JdtCompiler.java:467)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder$CompileMoreLater.compile(CompilationStateBuilder.java:142)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder.doBuildFrom(CompilationStateBuilder.java:281)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder.buildFrom(CompilationStateBuilder.java:182)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDef.getCompilationState(ModuleDef.java:280)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:502)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:414)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:201)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler$1.run(Compiler.java:152)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.doRun(CompileTaskRunner.java:87)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.runWithAppropriateLogger(CompileTaskRunner.java:81)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.main(Compiler.java:159)
```

My module definition is:

```
<module>
    <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User'/>
    <inherits name="com.google.gwt.i18n.I18N"/>
    <inherits name='othermodule.Main' />

    <entry-point class='mymodule.client.GWT_TESTS'/>
</module>
```

How to resolve this kind of compilation problem? Am I forgetting inheriting from other modules (I tried to add the those where classes were not resolved even they should be inherited via User module and it did not help)? Is there anything in my Eclipse project setting that I am missing (mymodule is in a separate project, GWT configured, gwt 2.0.4, other modules and JARs are set in project dependencies)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I deleted the project and recreated it again and it works now. I originally used GWT that came with Eclipse plugin (2.3.0) but then I had to change GWT version to 2.0.4. Either changing the GWT version for existing project or another of my change when I was resolving the problem caused the error.