# NoSuchMethodError with GWT

Tags: java, gwt

I had a GWT app that was working fine. Then I added `guava-r09.jar` and `guava-r09-gwt.jar`, and messed around with the build path a bit. Now, when I try to launch my app in hosted mode, I get this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.util.Set.java_lang_Iterable_iterator()Ljava/util/Iterator;
    at com.google.gwt.user.cellview.client.CellBasedWidgetImpl.sinkEvents(CellBasedWidgetImpl.java:117)
    at com.google.gwt.user.cellview.client.AbstractHasData.(AbstractHasData.java:279)
    at com.google.gwt.user.cellview.client.CellList.(CellList.java:211)
    at com.google.gwt.user.cellview.client.CellList.(CellList.java:175)
    at com.my.client.myMainView.(MainView.java:33)
```

I have found various sites that propose solutions ([Tim Mattisson's blog](http://blog.timmattison.com/archives/2009/11/08/how-to-fix-error-unexpected-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-messages-when-compiling-gwt-code-in-eclipse/) and [ForgetMeNotes](http://forgetmenotes.blogspot.com/2009/05/gwteclipse-nosuchmethoderror.html)). I took the advice they listed there (re-ordering the build path), but my problem persists. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: I had a similar problem (some classes from gwt-user.jar were not visible when compiling my module). I must have messed up my project somehow. What I remember I did was that I changed gwt version from the one that came with GWT Eclipse plugin to a previous version. See my post here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6610526/402755

Comment: This is a late comment, but do you have a subclass of JavaScriptObject that implements Iterable, by chance?  That can break development mode: http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=4864

Comment: Bill's comment is correct; this exception happens when trying to implement an Iterable JSO.  Unless you want to super-source java.lang.Iterable and add a @SingleJsoImpl() annotation pointing to the one and only js class allows to use iterable, you're pretty much S.O.L.